# How do I stop this decode error in python Json

Tags: python, json, decode

im practicing with python json, and i made a function that opens a file, and loads the number that was stored in that file, but if that file does not exist, it excepts the error, and ask for input for a favorite number, then dumps that number in the file, then loads it. but i keep getting an error

```
import json

def get_num():
    filename = 'numberssfresdfs.json'
    try:
        with open(filename) as num:
            number = json.load(num)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        favorite_num = input("Please enter your favorite number ")
        with open(filename, 'w') as num:
            json.dump(favorite_num, num)
            print("Your favorite number is " )
    else:
        print("I know your favorite number, its " + str(number))

get_num()
```

I keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "remember_favorite_num.py", line 16, in <module>
  get_num()
File "remember_favorite_num.py", line 7, in get_num
  number = json.load(num)
File "C:\Users\kenda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
  32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
File "C:\Users\kenda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
  32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\kenda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
  32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
  obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\kenda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
  32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
  raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
  json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: This is coming up too often; I'm almost certain that what you have is [jsonlines](http://jsonlines.org/). In other words, each line can be parsed as a valid JSON object, but the file as a whole cannot. `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` is the the giveaway because it's saying the first character of the second row is invalid... which is right after `\n` broke the JSON format.

Comment: yea im really new to python and can't really understand what that means

Answer (score 0):

You are never reaching the code in your except block because numberssfresdfs.json does exist.

You are getting the json.load error message because numberssfresdfs.json does not contain valid json or is empty.

You can use a json linter ([one online linter](https://jsonlint.com/)) to validate that your file contains valid json.

Once you confirm you are working with valid json, you can work through the rest of your logic.